# MS Edge vertical tabs: scroll to active tab?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, microsoft-edge-extension

In MS Edge with a lot of vertical tabs when a newly created tab moved to near the top, it scrolls the tabs to the bottom, making active (new) tab out of sight.
Is there a way prevent tabs from scrolling or at least scroll to the active tab?

`background.js`

```
/* listen for new tab event */
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener( tab =>
{
  /* move tab to the top */
  chrome.tabs.move(tab.id, {index: 0});
});
```

`manifest.json`

```
{
   "background": {
      "persistent": true,
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "description": "open new tabs as first tab",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "test",
   "permissions": [ "tabs" ],
   "version": "0.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the only solution I could find is track previous active tab and when new tab moved, activate previous tab, wait 200ms and activate new tab (delay less than 200ms seems to be very unreliable). It works, but unfortunately it visibly scrolls the tabs.

```
var lastActiveTab = {};
/* collect active tab for each window at startup */
chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, tabs =>
{
  for(let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
  {
    lastActiveTab[tabs[i].windowId] = tabs[0];
  }
})

/* listen for tab switch */
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener( info =>
{
  /* work around for a bug https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1213925 */
  setTimeout(() =>
  {
    /* track active tab */
    chrome.tabs.get(info.tabId, tab => lastActiveTab[tab.windowId] = tab);
  }, 300);
});

/* listen for new tab event */
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener( tab =>
{
  /* move tab to the top */
  chrome.tabs.move(tab.id, {index: 0});
  /* activate previous tab */
  chrome.tabs.update(lastActiveTab[tab.windowId].id, {active: true});
  /* wait 200ms and activate new tab */
  setTimeout(() => chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {active: true}), 200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution for this issue. You can mark your answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

With MS Edge vertical tabs layout a possible solution may be to pin the tab in this way.

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener( tab => {
    chrome.tabs.move(tab.id, {index: 0}, t => {
        chrome.tabs.update(t.id, {pinned: true})
    })
});
```

**EDIT**: Pinning a tab moves it to the top position**S**, so chrome.tab.move may not be necessary

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work if a tab needed to be moved to a specific place, not just to the beginning.